# How do you reference and dereference a cstring array in a function for C?

Tags: c

```
char *wordList[15];
```

This is the char point array, my question is if I were to put in a function like this:

```
decodeMessage(input, wordList);
```

how would I dereference it in the function so changes could be made to it?

Comment: Examples: `wordList[0]`, `wordList[0][0]`...

Comment: "changes could be made to it" - to the values in the array, or reallocating the whole array i.e. changing the wordList pointer itself?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are converted to a pointer to the first element when passed to a function.

As a result, changes to array elements in the function involve a pointer dereference and thus are visible from the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

You would access it as you would any array.

```c
char* wordList[15]; // ... initialization

char* firstItem = wordList[0];
char* secondItem = wordList[1];
// ... so on
```